# Android Studio Layout Validation bug?

Tags: java, android, xml

sorry for my English
My problem with android studio is that the "EditText" are transparent in the Layout Validation but once the program is executed on my real hardware (my phone) they appear most normally
So I change the project to see, but the problem is still there
So it's clearly my software that bug.

XML code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="EditText test"/> </LinearLayout>
```

Screen:

[image: Layout validation empty, but still appears in the split]

Thank you for helping me
Cordially.